# How to make a hidden div appear then fade out (at random times if possible)?

Tags: jquery

Basically I am creating a sort of 8-bit city scene.

I have three divs:

#city-back - the background behind the city
 #city-middle - the div I want "flashing at random" which is currently display:none
 #city-front - the image of the 8-bit city

What I need is for the #city-middle div to suddenly appear, then quickly fade out after half a second to sort-of imitate distant thunder/lightning.

Is it possible to have it do this in a random interval between 3 - 8 seconds so that it looks a lot more realistic rather than it looking like a looped animation?

I have tried looking up ways via jQuery, however this is a bit too advanced for my knowledge!

EDIT: So I've uploaded what I have so far to jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/At8et/1/ 
Works fine for me on my browser running locally, but not on JSFiddle?

Comment: Please show us what you've attempted so far.

Comment: Do a little searching on SO and/or read the jQuery docs. There are a few free freelancers here, but not many.

Comment: what you want to do is possible with jQuery but you should post your markup as a code or as a fiddle

Comment: Apologies guys, first time using this site. Just realised I need to start again as I had the city-front as a child element of city-middle! I'll post up revised markup shortly..

Comment: Uploaded to JSFiddle using Sumurai8's code http://jsfiddle.net/At8et/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math.random()` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)) and `window.setTimeout()` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)).

```
//Show, then hide again after 0.2 - 1 seconds
function showCity() {
  $('#city-middle').show();
  window.setTimeout( hideCity, 200 + (Math.random() * 800) );
}

//Hide, then show again after 3-8 seconds
function hideCity() {
  $('#city-middle').hide();
  window.setTimeout( showCity, 3000 + (Math.random() * 5000) );
}

hideCity();
```

Comment: This one worked great for me! I changed .hide to .fadeOut. One issue is that I need the the showCity to literally appear and then initiate the hide/fadeout after a split second, rather than between 0.2 - 1. When I change the 200 + (Math.random() * 800 to just a numerical value, it doesnt work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, forgot to remove an extra bracket! All works perfectly now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
function flash(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#city-middle").show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#city-middle").fadeOut("fast");
        },100);
        flash();
    },(Math.random()*5000)+200);
}
```